# PDE non homogenous boundary conditions in 2D

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

For a partial differential equation, let's say the wave equation, with non homogeneous boundary conditions (whether is a mixed boundary value problem or not, but not infinite case) in 2D, do we proceed as we do in a 1D PDE?

I was solving a homogeneous wave equation in 2D and then I tried to extend it with non homogeneous b.c. My first try was to solve it as a 1D problem, finding the particular solution first by $u(x,y,t)=u_h(x,y,t)+\psi(x,y)$, but then I got a function $\psi''(x,y)$ and I thought it won't give me much information, as it is the integration of a gradient. Later, I tried to treat it as a homogeneous problem and apply the b.c. in the solutions for $X(x)$ and $Y(y)$ directly. As it was expected, I couldn't find one of the eigenvalues because of the non-homogeneous nature on the b.c. Is there a concept that I am not applying correctly or something that I am forgetting? or is the procedure totally wrong?

I know this must be a fundamental part on the resolution of the PDE, but I've been struggling with this not knowing how to proceed for a long period. Thanks for your time.